# Unable to boot Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

Any know how to add windows 10 to my boot menu, I have windows 10 installed in a separate drive,I don't know how to edit the grub menu to show the windows boot option. I have disabled my UEFI and changed to legacy and changed the boot order but that did't work.
When I installed Ubuntu 18.1 after windows it did not give the option to install alongside of Windows 10.

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode or both in Legacy/BIOS boot mode? Grub only boots working Windows that is in same boot mode UEFI or BIOS. Fast start up must be off in Windows: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: If Windows was originally installed under UEFI and you've changed to legacy, it wont boot anymore. Here are instructions on how to convert a working Windows install from UEFI to Legacy: https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=580      And here's a link to a little tool directly from Microsoft to do the conversion: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt  I would probably try to switch back first and see if you can get Windows to boot. If not, you're probably looking at a slightly more complicated issue.

Comment: Thanks, Windows was installed in UEFI and Ubuntu under legacy(system would not boot to install usb under UEFI) probably why it did not offer the option to install Ubuntu alongside windows?